# Multidimensional Array with Maximum Slots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck at this jQuery array and trying my luck here on Stack Overflow. Not sure where I am making the mistake.

The purpose of this function is to create an array that holds the selected items with sub list and alert when the list maximum select is reached.
A staff can select a dish e.g. Kebab. which can only be configured SALAD, SAUCE to a maximum input

The array should be

```
var id = 0;
var Option = $(this).attr('ConfigName') // SALAD

if (typeof (FOODS[id][Option]) == "undefined") {
    FOODS[id][Option]={};
}

FOODS[id][Option ][0]="ONION"
FOODS[id][Option ][1]="LETTUCE"
FOODS[id][Option ][2]="CARROT" 

// Option changed to SAUCE
FOODS[id][Option][0]="MAYO"
FOODS[id][Option][1]="KETCHUP"

if(FOODS[id][Option].length<MaxSelect){
   alert("Max Option Selected")
}
```

When there is another dish added then this would increment the id and store again with above method.

When I coded above with jQuery it keep shows error FOODS[id][Option] is undefined.

Comment: Please show the code that defines `FOODS`; otherwise, well, it's undefined :).

Comment: He defines FOODS[id][Option]={}; - as an object, later on he tries to use it as an array.

Comment: var FOODS= []; - this is actually created before the page loaded

Comment: btw, `if(FOODS[id][Option].length<MaxSelect)` condition seems suspicious to me. Also, you miss many many semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

If `FOODS` is an Array, initialized to `[]`, then this is how the line `if (typeof (FOODS[id][Option]) == "undefined") {` is evaluated:

```
FOODS                                    => ok, value is []
id                                       => ok, value is 0
Option                                   => ok, value is "SALAD"
FOODS[id] = [][0]                        => ok, value is undefined
FOODS[id][Option] = undefined["SALAD"]   => TypeError, cannot access property of undefined
```

Because you're trying to access a property of the value `undefined`, JavaScript will throw an error.

You need to initialize `FOODS[id]`, something like this:

```
if (!(id in FOODS)) {
  FOODS[id] = {};
}
if (typeof (FOODS[id][Option]) == "undefined") {
    FOODS[id][Option]={}; // See below; this is also wrong
}
```

This isn't the only problem. You're also conflating *objects* with *arrays*. Although you can assign numeric keys to an object, you're not going to be able to check `length` on that object; that's only a feature of Arrays. So change `FOODS[id][Option]={};` to `FOODS[id][Option]=[];`.